# vb error: can't convert nvchar to numeric

Tags: mysql, vb.net, sql-server-2012

Can anyone shed light onto why I get this error about how it can't convert a `nvarchar` to `numeric`?

1. there are no `nvarchar` columns in the db table
2. running on SQL Server 2012 migrated from MySQL 5+
3. All columns allow NULLs so an empty form should still post.

Code:

```
    Try
            sql.SQLCon.ConnectionString = sql.ConnectionString
            sql.SQLCon.Open()
            sql.SQLcmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT into lab_oop_data(press_setup,test_drop_time,shift,operator,batch_num,split_batch_num,thickness,press_speed,oop_target_thickness,resin_usage,batch_solids,dosing_rate,combi_dosing,wax_dosing,buffer,urea,total_sander_dust,batch_solids2,dosing_rate2,combi_dosing2,wax_dosing2,buffer2,urea2,total_sander_dust2,pt_zone1,pt_zone2,pt_zone3,pt_zone4,pt_zone5,mat_weights,moisture_target,moisture_percent,plate_hours_core,plate_hours_face,shives_core,shives_face,density_set,density_1,density_2,density_3,density_4,density_5,density_6,density_7,density_8,density_9,density_10,density_ave,thickness_1,thickness_2,thickness_3,thickness_4,thickness_5,thickness_6,thickness_7,thickness_8,thickness_9,thickness_10,thickness_ave,int_bond_1,int_bond_2,int_bond_3,int_bond_4,int_bond_5,int_bond_6,int_bond_7,int_bond_8,int_bond_9,int_bond_10,int_bond_ave,where_broke_1,where_broke_2,where_broke_3,where_broke_4,where_broke_5,where_broke_6,where_broke_7,where_broke_8,where_broke_9,where_broke_10,repull_1,repull_2,repull_3,repull_4,repull_5,repull_6,repull_7,repull_8,repull_9,repull_10,mi_thickness_1,mi_thickness_2,mi_thickness_3,mi_thickness_4,mi_thickness_5,mi_thickness_6,mi_thickness_7,mi_thickness_8,mi_thickness_9,mi_thickness_10,mi_thickness_ave,south_edge,south_centre,north_centre,north_edge,pl_test1,pl_test2,pw_south,pw_north,lcl_south,lcl_north,lcw_south,lcw_north,intended_grade,assigned_grade,assigned_grade2,pcf,psi,strip_den_tar_thick,strip_den_ave_thick,sb_s1_top,sb_s1_bottom,sb_s2_top,sb_s2_bottom,notes) values(@PressSetup,@TestDropTime,@Shift,@Operator,@BatchNum,@SplitBatchNum,@Thickness,@PressSpeed,@TargetThickness,@ResinUsage,@BatchSolidsFace,@DosingRateFace,@CombiDosingFace,@WaxDosingFace,@BufferFace,@UreaFace,@TotalSanderDustFace,@BatchSolidsCore,@DosingRateCore,@CombiDosingCore,@WaxDosingCore,@BufferCore,@UreaCore,@TotalSanderDustCore,@Zone1,@Zone2,@Zone3,@Zone4,@Zone5,@MatWeights,@MoistureTarget,@MoisturePercent,@PlateHoursCore,@PlateHoursFace,@ShivesCore,@ShivesFace,@DensitySet,@Density1,@Density2,@Density3,@Density4,@Density5,@Density6,@Density7,@Density8,@Density9,@Density10,@DensityAve,@Thickness1,@Thickness2,@Thickness3,@Thickness4,@Thickness5,@Thickness6,@Thickness7,@Thickness8,@Thickness9,@Thickness10,@ThicknessAve,@InternalBond1,@InternalBond2,@InternalBond3,@InternalBond4,@InternalBond5,@InternalBond6,@InternalBond7,@InternalBond8,@InternalBond9,@InternalBond10,@InternalBondAve,@WhereBroke1,@WhereBroke2,@WhereBroke3,@WhereBroke4,@WhereBroke5,@WhereBroke6,@WhereBroke7,@WhereBroke8,@WhereBroke9,@WhereBroke10,@Repull1,@Repull2,@Repull3,@Repull4,@Repull5,@Repull6,@Repull7,@Repull8,@Repull9,@Repull10,@MiThickness1,@MiThickness2,@MiThickness3,@MiThickness4,@MiThickness5,@MiThickness6,@MiThickness7,@MiThickness8,@MiThickness9,@MiThickness10,@MiThicknessAve,@SouthEdge,@SouthCentre,@NorthCentre,@NorthEdge,@PanelLengthSouth,@PanelLengthNorth,@PanelWidthSouth,@PanelWidthNorth,@LabCutLengthSouth,@LabCutLengthNorth,@LabCutWeightSouth,@LabCutWeightNorth,@IntendedGrade,@AssignedGradeNorth,@AssignedGradeSouth,@PCF,@PSI,@SDTT,@SDAT,@SurfaceBondS1a,@SurfaceBondS1b,@SurfaceBondS2a,@SurfaceBondS2b,@Notes)", sql.SQLCon)

            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PressSetup", PressSetup.SelectedText)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TestDropTime", TestDropTime.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Shift", Shift.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Operator", "bdoucette")
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BatchNum", BatchNum.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SplitBatchNum", SplitBatchNum.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Thickness", Thickness.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PressSpeed", PressSpeed.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TargetThickness", TargetThickness.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResinUsage", ResinUsage.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BatchSolidsFace", BatchSolidsFace.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BatchSolidsCore", BatchSolidsCore.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DosingRateFace", DosingRateFace.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DosingRateCore", DosingRateCore.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CombiDosingFace", CombiDosingFace.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CombiDosingCore", CombiDosingCore.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WaxDosingFace", WaxDosingFace.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WaxDosingCore", WaxDosingCore.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BufferFace", BufferFace.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BufferCore", BufferCore.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UreaFace", UreaFace.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UreaCore", UreaCore.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalSanderDustFace", TotalSanderDustFace.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalSanderDustCore", TotalSanderDustCore.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zone1", Zone1.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zone2", Zone2.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zone3", Zone3.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zone4", Zone4.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zone5", Zone5.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MatWeights", MatWeights.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MoistureTarget", MoistureTarget.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MoisturePercent", MoisturePercent.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlateHoursFace", PlateHoursFace.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlateHoursCore", PlateHoursCore.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShivesFace", ShivesFace.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShivesCore", ShivesCore.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DensitySet", DensitySet.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Density1", Density1.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Density2", Density2.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Density3", Density3.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Density4", Density4.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Density5", Density5.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Density6", Density6.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Density7", Density7.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Density8", Density8.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Density9", Density9.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Density10", Density10.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DensityAve", DensityAve.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Thickness1", Thickness1.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Thickness2", Thickness2.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Thickness3", Thickness3.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Thickness4", Thickness4.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Thickness5", Thickness5.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Thickness6", Thickness6.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Thickness7", Thickness7.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Thickness8", Thickness8.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Thickness9", Thickness9.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Thickness10", Thickness10.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ThicknessAve", ThicknessAve.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InternalBond1", InternalBond1.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InternalBond2", InternalBond2.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InternalBond3", InternalBond3.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InternalBond4", InternalBond4.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InternalBond5", InternalBond5.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InternalBond6", InternalBond6.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InternalBond7", InternalBond7.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InternalBond8", InternalBond8.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InternalBond9", InternalBond9.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InternalBond10", InternalBond10.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InternalBondAve", InternalBondAve.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WhereBroke1", WhereBroke1.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WhereBroke2", WhereBroke2.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WhereBroke3", WhereBroke3.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WhereBroke4", WhereBroke4.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WhereBroke5", WhereBroke5.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WhereBroke6", WhereBroke6.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WhereBroke7", WhereBroke7.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WhereBroke8", WhereBroke8.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WhereBroke9", WhereBroke9.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WhereBroke10", WhereBroke10.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Repull1", Repull1.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Repull2", Repull2.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Repull3", Repull3.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Repull4", Repull4.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Repull5", Repull5.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Repull6", Repull6.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Repull7", Repull7.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Repull8", Repull8.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Repull9", Repull9.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Repull10", Repull10.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiThickness1", MiThickness1.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiThickness2", MiThickness2.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiThickness3", MiThickness3.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiThickness4", MiThickness4.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiThickness5", MiThickness5.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiThickness6", MiThickness6.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiThickness7", MiThickness7.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiThickness8", MiThickness8.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiThickness9", MiThickness9.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiThickness10", MiThickness10.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiThicknessAve", MiThicknessAve.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SouthEdge", SouthEdge.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SouthCentre", SouthCentre.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NorthCentre", NorthCentre.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NorthEdge", NorthEdge.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PanelLengthSouth", PanelLengthSouth.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PanelLengthNorth", PanelLengthNorth.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PanelWidthSouth", PanelWidthSouth.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PanelWidthNorth", PanelWidthNorth.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LabCutLengthSouth", LabCutLengthSouth.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LabCutLengthNorth", LabCutLengthNorth.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LabCutWeightSouth", LabCutWeightSouth.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LabCutWeightNorth", LabCutWeightNorth.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IntendedGrade", IntendedGrade.SelectedText)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AssignedGradeSouth", AssignedGradeSouth.SelectedText)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AssignedGradeNorth", AssignedGradeNorth.SelectedText)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PCF", PCF.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PSI", InternalBondAve.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SDTT", SDTT.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SDAT", SDAT.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SurfaceBondS1a", sbSample1a.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SurfaceBondS1b", sbSample1b.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SurfaceBondS2a", sbSample2a.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SurfaceBondS2b", sbSample2b.Text)
            sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", Notes.Text)

            sql.SQLcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            sql.SQLCon.Close()
            sql.SQLCon.Dispose()
        End Try
```

Comment: I should note that I created a test table with one column INT and other TEXT and I post an empty form into it and it works.

Comment: Are you sure that no strings are entered into your "Text" fields? If there are then there's your issue as you have stated that "there are no nvchar columns in the db table"...

Comment: `1) there are no nvchar columns in the db table` -- The error isn't that your table is expecting a `NVARCHAR` value, it's that it is expecting a `NUMERIC` value and what you passed in wasn't a number.

Comment: Also look at "@Operator" param you assign it a string, that's one issue there...

Comment: Doesnt a Text field accept strings?

Comment: That `nvchar` referenced in the error message is not from the table. Like you said there are no `nvchar`. Instead SQLcmd here is guessing each data type for you incoming fields. It has guessed one of those `.text` items as `nvchar` even though the table fields is Numeric. So it's freaking out when it can't convert the assumed `nvchar` value to a number, and throwing the error. Andrew Morton's answer below suggests being more explicit about the field type of incoming data. Which makes a lot of sense.

Comment: In the database the operator column is TEXT

Comment: I will update the code and see what happens... I'll keep you all posted.

Comment: OK. so as I was updating code... I found that I was using .text for the datetimepicker.... I switched it to .value and now I get a new error:

Operand Type Clash: datetime is incompatible with text

the database column type is datetime :/

Comment: sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TestDropTime", TestDropTime.Text)

sql.SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TestDropTime", TestDropTime.Value)

Answer (score 1):

`.AddWithValue` looks at the type of the value you've given it and makes a guess as to what type to use in SQL. This may not be what you want.

To avoid all ambiguity, you are better off using something more like

```
sql.sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@PressSetup",
                                             .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Float,
                                             .Value = CDbl(PressSetup.SelectedText)})
```

Also, you may want `.SelectedValue` instead of `.SelectedText`.

Comment: Since the database accepts nulls, wouldnt the form still post without an error?

Comment: Is there a way I can narrow down where the query is faulting. A better method of error reporting?

Comment: @BrettEzra You're going to have to check each `.Text` to see if it represents what should be a null value in the database and set the `.Value = DBNull.Value`. I foresee a lot of typing in your immediate future, but once it is done you will have reliable code. With that many parameters to do, it might be easier to write a little program to translate what you have so far into what you need.